# Using Python to Parse JSON and Insert into SQLite3 Database

Tags: python, json, parsing, sqlite

I'm currently parsing the following document.  I also created a dummy sqlite3 db with a table.  Ideally I'd like to take the "print e" and "print f" statements and insert those keys as column names.  In addition, I'd like to take "print data[e]" and "print participants_data[f]" and use these as the corresponding values.  I tried doing the "insert into tablename values (?,?,?,?,?)" python code, but I'm afraid I'm not fully understanding this.  Does anyone know how to insert these lines into a generic table in sqlite3 via python?

Data:

```
{
   "matchId": 1778839570,
   "region": "NA",
   "platformId": "NA1",
   "matchMode": "CLASSIC",
   "matchType": "MATCHED_GAME",
   "matchCreation": 1427867835805,
   "matchDuration": 3424,
   "queueType": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
   "mapId": 11,
   "season": "SEASON2015",
   "matchVersion": "5.6.0.194",
   "participants": [
      {
         "teamId": 100,
         "spell1Id": 4,
         "spell2Id": 11,
         "championId": 113,
         "highestAchievedSeasonTier": "GOLD"
      }
   ]
}
```

Code:

```
import sqlite3
import json

with open('data.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

for e in data:
    if e == 'participants':
        participants_data=data['participants'][0]
        print participants_data
        for f in participants_data:
            print f
            print participants_data[f]  
    else:
        print e
        print data[e]


# # let's put this in sql
conn = sqlite3.connect('somedbname.sqlite')
c = conn.cursor()
#create_database
sql = 'create table if not exists tablename'
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE stocks
             (date text, trans text, symbol text, qty real, price real)''')
conn.commit()

c.execute("INSERT INTO stocks VALUES ('2006-01-05','BUY','RHAT',100,35.14)")
conn.commit()
c.execute("select * from stocks")
print(c.fetchall())
```

Edit: 2nd Attempt at the Code:

```
import sqlite3
import json

with open('data.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

for e in data:
    if e == 'participants':
        participants_data=data['participants'][0]
        print participants_data
        for f in participants_data:
            print f
            print participants_data[f]  
    else:
        print e
        print data[e]

api = data

# # let's put this in sql
conn = sqlite3.connect('somedbname.sqlite')
c = conn.cursor()
#create_database
sql = 'create table if not exists tablename'
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE if not exists stocks3
             (col1 text, col2 text, col3 text, col4 text, col5 text, col6 text, col7 text, col8 text, col9 text, col10 text, col11 text, col12 text)''')
conn.commit()

c.execute("INSERT INTO stocks3 VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", api)
conn.commit()
c.execute("select * from stocks")
print(c.fetchall())
```

Comment: It seems like you're trying to learn python, relational databases, and how to use a relational database from a programming language all at the same time. It would be easiest if you gave an example data file, and explained what you want the columns in the database to be, and what you want the rows in the database to look like for the example data.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding your point, print statements only do that: they print the data to your screen. So your whole loop where you do for e in data is only being put on your screen. You should first put the data in the format you want and then parse it.  Instead of using SQLite, you might want to consider PGSql, which has a built in JSON object.  That way you can insert your JSON and query it using the DOM or parse it out using SQL.